# Haskell input and output?

Tags: haskell, input, io

I have a program that I've written in Haskell, and everything except the IO is working.
The IO is meant to do the following:
 - Take in a number from the user
 - If this number is positive, read that many lines into a list, then take the number and created list and pass it to a function which will return the output
 - If this number is negative instead, only read the next line, and take the number and that line and pass it to a function which returns other output

I've been using "interpret (unlines . map program . lines)" bit of code for testing purposes, but I'm not sure how to make it handle multiple line input (especially when the number of lines isn't constant)

I would appreciate any help

Ahh yes, and the program loops

More details:
The program itself handles quadtrees.
Input can be along the lines of this:
8
00000000
00111111
00001111
00001111
00011111
00111100
00111000
In which case the program sees the 8, the size of the picture, and builds its corresponding quadtree. The output is rather convoluted, but basically it turns it into a text representation of the quadtree's structure.

Current program:

```
module Main where

main = interact (unlines . map program . lines) -- the IO here is bologna, as it doesn't do anything with the user input
--turns ones and zeros into easier to distinguish characters
replace 0 = '.'
replace 1 = '*'
program x = display (toArray 8 (t2)) -- just a test case to see if the important functions work, as well as a placeholder for real IO, hopefully
data Quadtree a = Tip | Node a (Quadtree a) (Quadtree a) (Quadtree a) (Quadtree a) -- the quadtree datastructure
leaf x = Node x Tip Tip Tip Tip -- saves some typing
-- this function takes a quadtree and returns a 2-dimensional list of binary digits to draw the picture
toArray a (Node x Tip Tip Tip Tip) = replicate a (replicate a x) 
toArray a (Node x b c d e) = (zipWith (++) (toArray (div a 2) b) (toArray (div a 2) c)) ++ (zipWith (++) (toArray (div a 2) d) (toArray (div a 2) e))
display x = unlines (map (map replace) x) -- gives a printable form of the two dimensional array
-- function that turns a number from base five
basefive x
    | x < 5 = x
    | x >= 5 = basefive (div x 5) * 10 + (mod x 5)
-- inserts into quadtree
insert [] (Node 0 Tip Tip Tip Tip) = Node 1 Tip Tip Tip Tip
insert (x:xs) (Node 0 Tip Tip Tip Tip)
    | x == '1' = Node 2 (insert xs (leaf 0)) (leaf 0) (leaf 0) (leaf 0)
    | x == '2' = Node 2 (leaf 0) (insert xs (leaf 0)) (leaf 0) (leaf 0)
    | x == '3' = Node 2 (leaf 0) (leaf 0) (insert xs (leaf 0)) (leaf 0)
    | x == '4' = Node 2 (leaf 0) (leaf 0) (leaf 0) (insert xs (leaf 0))
insert (x:xs) (Node a b c d e)
    | x == '1' = Node a (insert xs b) c d e
    | x == '2' = Node a b (insert xs c) d e
    | x == '3' = Node a b c (insert xs d) e
    | x == '4' = Node a b c d (insert xs e)
-- builds quadtree from scratch
insertall [] x = x
insertall (x:xs) y = insert x (insertall xs y)
s1 = "9 14 17 22 23 44 63 69 88 94 113" -- the example quadtree "path"; it represents the structure
s2 = ["00000000","00000000","00001111","00001111","00011111","00111111","00111100","00111000"] -- this represents the image
-- function which splits a list in half
split :: [a] -> ([a],[a])
split xs = go xs xs where
  go (x:xs) (_:_:zs) = (x:us,vs) where (us,vs)=go xs zs
  go    xs   _       = ([],xs)
quarter a b c = ((a . split) (map (b . split) c)) -- function which quarters a 2 dimensional list
-- function which takes a 2 dimensional array and returns its tree
toTree a x
    | x == replicate a (replicate a '1') = (leaf 1)
    | x == replicate a (replicate a '0') = (leaf 0)
    | otherwise = Node 2 (toTree (div a 2) (quarter fst fst x)) (toTree (div a 2) (quarter fst snd x)) (toTree (div a 2) (quarter snd fst x)) (toTree (div a 2) (quarter snd snd x))
t2 = toTree 8 s2
```

Both s1 and s2 are sample user inputs; the random eights thrown around is the size of the quadtree image, which is supposed to also be supplied by the user

Comment: Are you currently using any IO at all, or just running a pure function from GHCi? Also, it looks like you're expecting to treat all input lines more uniformly than really makes sense; you'll need to iterate through the input list one way or another. It's hard to be sure what you're doing without more code, though.

Comment: I might as well not be using an IO right now. I feel like posting any code might just detract from the main question, but the program as a whole is supposed to handle quadtrees. If the user puts in a positive number, it means they're about to put in a picture of a quadtree with binary digits, and the number they put in is the size. I will edit this into the question.

Comment: But the IO code is what we'd need to help you write good IO code.

Comment: Ahh, very well. But I will have to clean it up first

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you really have a spec for a function:

> Take in a number from the user - If this number is positive, read that many lines into a list, then take the number and created list and pass it to a function which will return the output - If this number is negative instead, only read the next line, and take the number and that line and pass it to a function which returns other output.

We can just write that function straightforwardly.

```
interactiveFun f g = do
       let readInt :: String -> Int
           readInt = read
       x <- fmap readInt getLine
       if x > 0
           then print . f . map readInt =<< replicateM x getLine
           else print . g x . readInt =<< getLine
```

**Edit**: `<$>` is the same an infix `fmap`, and comes from Control.Applicative. Its idiomatic Haskell, but I've edited it out for simplicity. `replicateM` comes from Control.Monad. You should import it and use it -- many many everyday Haskell functions come from base libraries other than the `Prelude`. All those base libraries are part of the standard, are portable, are useful, and should be used liberally.

Comment: I'm seeing an error that I've gotten before. "parse error on input `='"? It's referring to the readInt = read part

Comment: @user1006042 Probably wrong indentation, have you aligned the 'r's from the signature and the definition?

Comment: Ahh yes, thank you. Coming from imperative, indentation will probably get me often. Probably the last thing, what is the <$> and replicateM? I don't recognize them, and neither does my compiler it seems. If I have to import anything, I'd prefer to avoid that if possible

Comment: @user1006042: The `<$>` operator is from `Control.Applicative` and is the same as the `fmap` function. `replicateM` is from `Control.Monad`, and is the same as using `replicate` and then `sequence` on the resulting list. Those are both standard modules from the language definition, but the alternatives I gave should all be imported by default.

Comment: Alright, well I replaced the functions with their counterparts (<$> with what you have and replicateM with sequence (replicate ... etc. I definately feel like some progress is occurring, but when I change "interactiveFun" to "main" (It says "not in scope 'main'" otherwise), it comes up with "Couldn't match expected type `IO t' against inferred type `([Int] -> c) -> (Int -> Int -> c1) -> IO ()'". And thank you for keeping tabs on this question.

Comment: Ahh, things are beginning to become clear... Thank you very much good sir!